# SQL Server 2008, getting column back as output parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have the following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_web_orders_insert]
(
    @userId int = default,
    @custId int = default,
    @orderDate datetime = default,
    @orderTotal money = default,
    @statusId int = default,
    @orderReference varchar(50) = default,
    @custReference varchar(50) = default,
    @order_ID INT output,
    @orderReferenceOutput varchar(50) output
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    INSERT INTO [web_orders] ([user_ID], [cust_ID], [orderDate], [orderTotal], [statusId], [orderReference], [custReference]) 
    VALUES (@userId, @custId, @orderDate, @orderTotal, @statusId , 'PLC' + REPLICATE('0', (7 - LEN((select MAX(order_ID) from web_orders)))) +  CAST((select(max(order_ID)+1) from web_orders) AS VARCHAR(5)), @custReference);

    SET @order_ID = @@IDENTITY

    SET @orderReferenceOutput = select top 1 orderReference from web_orders
```

But getting syntax issue near select, how can I get back the value for `orderReference` which I have just inserted ?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points:

- use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` (see [why this is here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/) or Google for it...)
- use a `SELECT` statement to get your value back

Something like:

```
SET @order_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT 
    @orderReferenceOutput = SELECT orderReference  
                            FROM dbo.web_orders
                            WHERE order_Id = @order_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following code part, hope it will help you

```
SET @orderReferenceOutput = select @orderReference=(top 1 orderReference) from web_orders
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select @order_ID = order_ID, @orderReferenceOutput = orderReference  
  from dbo.web_orders
  where order_ID = SCOPED_IDENTITIY();
```

Or get rid of output parameters and return inserted record directly:

```
select * from dbo.web_orders where order_Id = SCOPED_IDENTITIY();
```

Yes. Procedures can return data, just like queries.